# How to make the height of a list dynamic in jaspersoftt studio?

Tags: jasper-reports

Good evening,

I have a `list` type element that contains **two text boxes**, when the **first text box is empty** it shows me the **white space between the previous text box** and the new one that is going to be printed.

However I would like to know If there is a way to **reduce that blank space**, that is to say that it is **printed as if that record did not exist**. As I mentioned above and probe with the print when expression and only "hide" but the **blank space is not disappeared**.

Comment: You should post the small *jrxml* to reproduce your problem and a screenshot

Comment: I hope you should place the **two text boxes**, which is inside the list, in frame component, that is modify your design from `List->Two Textboxes` to `List->Frame->Two Text boxes`. To know more about [**How `Frame` component helps reducing empty space** check this link](http://donotforgetitmaster.blogspot.in/2015/08/remove-empty-space-in-jasper-reports.html)